# Unable to call a function with button onclick in jQuery ajax table data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to perform delete operation on a dynamic table row data. For some reason when I click on the delete button the delete function is not getting called! Is there any problem in this code, if so please let me know.

I'm still at a beginner level.

```js
data = "";

// to delete

delete_ = function(user_email) {
  alert("inside delete");
};

myfunction = function() {
  $(".tablecontainer").show();
  load();
};

load = function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "updatedservicerequests",
    type: "POST",
    data: {},
    success: function(response) {
      alert(response.message);
      data = response.data;
      alert(response.data);
      $(".tr").remove();
      alert(response.data);
      $(function() {
        for (i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
          $("#table").append("<tr> <td> " + response.data[i].user_email + " </td> <td> " + response.data[i].booking_number + " </td> <td> " + response.data[i].booking_address + " </td> <td> " + response.data[i].booking_date + " </td> <td> " + response.data[i].booking_message + " </td> <td> " + response.data[i].request_date + " </td> <td> " + response.data[i].chosen_emails_1 + " </td> <td> " + response.data[i].chosen_emails_2 + " </td> <td> " + response.data[i].chosen_emails_3 + " </td> <td> <button onclick='edit(" + response.data[i].user_email + ");'> Edit </button> <br>    <button onclick='delete_(" + response.data[i].user_email + ");'> Delete </button> </td> </tr>");
        }
      });
    },

    error: function(response) {
      alert("unable to pull up any service request");
    }
  });

  //to prevent (contact-submit) button from submitting form data since submit button has default action of submitting form

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#contact-submit").click(function(e) {
      return false;
    });
  });
};
```

```html
<button onclick="myfunction();">Go</button>
<div class="tablecontainer" style="display: none;">
  th&gt;
  <table border="1" id="table">
    <tr>
      <th>booking_email</th>
      <th>booking_number</th>
      <th>booking_address</th>
      <th>booking_date</th>
      <th>booking_message</th>
      <th>when the request was made</th>
      <th>requested_tech_1</th>
      <th>requested_tech_2</th>
      <th>requested_tech_3</th>
      <th>operations</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I would suggest you remove the inline bindings, in favor of logical bindings, which you are already doing for the contact-submit.  This way you can separate your concerns between the markup and the logic.  Also, creating delegate event bindings for the dynamic elements would also allow you to create a single event binding, rather than duplicating inline bindings.

Comment: @JonKoops: my view is that your code edits are too much of an amendment, especially making HTML valid (quotes on attribute strings) and changing the quoting style in JavaScript. Some problems are due to a mistake in the code supplied, and excessive modifications can hide that problem, to the detriment of the question author. I suggest that you make your code edits much lighter, and only do them if the code really is unreadable - it was OK in this case.

Comment: Understandable. I was not aware of this, just wanted to make the code readable is all. Ran it through a formatter in order to be able to read the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem has a relatively simple solution. I personally use a jQuery table plugin called DataTables found [here](https://datatables.net/)

I would encourage you to look into it as it is definitely a powerful tool. As for your main question "How do I delete a row of data in the table?" It's relatively simple. So instead of using a for loop to iterate through the data, you can use jQuery's `.each` which is pretty easy too. I'm going to show you this method here and I can add more to my response later if you want to see a DataTables version.

```
# please note that I use ES6 syntax in JS.
# this: function() {...code here...}
# is the same as this: (()=> {...code here...});
# ES6 allows for shorthand annonymous functions

// wait for document to load
$(document).ready(()=> {
    // declare variable
    let foo = "hello world";
    // fetch data from the back end
    $.get("data.php?foo=" + encodeURIComponent(foo), (data)=> {
        # the $.get is the exact same as the AJAX code you used above but shorthanded
        // the 'data' is a parameter in the annonymous function that is storing the data from the back end
        console.log(data); // test that we are getting the data properly
        // remove table rows if they exist
        $("#mytable tbody").remove();
        $("#mytable").each(data, (i, item)=> {
            // add your data to the table by appending to the table
            # You would just continue this until you have all the cells you need filled. I'm going to skip to the end with adding the btn now
            $("#mytable").append('<tbody><tr><td>'+item.booking_email+'</td><td>'+item.booking_number+'</td><td><button class="btn btn-lg btn-danger deletebtn" id="'+item.booking_number+'">Delete</button></td></tbody>');
            /* the button has to have a unique ID to be called on so I assigned it the booking numbers to the ID. 
            Here's how we would call on it*/
            $(".deletebtn").unbind().click((d)=> {
                // you must unbind it first or you will have multiple events fire and you only want a single event to fire
                // pass the annonymous function a parameter (can be anything really I use d for delete)
                console.log(d.target.id); // check to make sure the button is getting an ID.
                // post to back end to delete then when it succeeds, we delete that row.
                $.post("data.php", {deletefoo: d.target.id}, (data)=> {
                    // delete row by calling on the target and removing the parent in this case being the row 'tr'
                    $(d.target).parents('tr').remove();
                });
            });
        });
        $("#mytable").show();
    });
});
```

I hope this helps your issue. Let me know if it helps/works for you or not.